# Automated C unit testing

Tags: c, eclipse, unit-testing, gcc, mingw

I have a C library compiled with MinGW, Eclipse C project. Library consists of many modules, each module can be tested.

What is the best way (using MACROS or something) how to write tests for this library, compile it a run it in Eclipse/CDT IDE?

**EDIT:** I've seen that some people use

```
#ifdef TEST

int main(void)
{
   ...TEST LOGIC...
}
#endif
```

but don't know how to plug it into Eclipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest to use [CuTest](http://cutest.sourceforge.net/) with a Makefile.