# Eclipse Add-on for unit testing in C

Tags: c, eclipse, unit-testing

I know there is a Eclipse add-on for junit testing available. That bring up a question, is there also a tool for C unit testing available?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794999/automated-c-unit-testing

Comment: There is a plug-in for CppUnit http://sourceforge.net/projects/ecut/

Comment: @BinyaminSharet Thanks for that link. that could help. But I actually search for a add-on similar to the junit add-on. With a optical signal (green or red bar) for the status of the code

Comment: @vard That's the kind of add-on I'm looking for, BUT I believe can not use that tool for `C`

Comment: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/cute-c-unit-testing-easier#.UIKe2W_MhHw

Answer (score 2):

The last Eclipse CDT release (juno) now has built-in support for C/C++ unit testing framework integration.

See the following [release note](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/NewIn81#C.2FC.2B.2B_Unit_Testing_Support) for more information.
This feature was originally developed [here](https://github.com/xgsa/cdt-tests-runner/wiki)

Answer (score -1):

After looking at the accompanying documentation and the setting configurations in the actual C/C++ testing plugin, it would appear that the CDT Testing tools only support C++ compatible frameworks:

- boost
- google
- QT

There's no built-in support for a tool like CUnit. I would advise switching over to another IDE like NetBeans.