# How to run cunit test in Eclipse?

Tags: c, eclipse, cunit

i want to run cunit test in my project and develop it use Eclipse, how to integrate the cunit to Eclipse, write and run the case. I have no idea about it, who can help me?

Comment: possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794999/automated-c-unit-testing

Answer (score -1):

I have a note how to do it. Hope it can help

http://www.evernote.com/shard/s226/sh/45f4e966-2a41-425f-9f56-b1d924eef186/870714cbfbe6ad8480bdb1effd72edcf

Comment: Please avoid link only answers; at least briefly summarize the link in your post.